# What's the deal with file load/compile order in RubyMotion?

Tags: rubymotion

I'm converting an existing iOS application from Objective-C to RubyMotion.

The first major pitfall I've hit is that the AppDelegate class refers to other classes defined in the app.

Since these are compiled after the AppDelegate class, it raises an exception:

```
2012-06-20 13:38:03.088 myApp[3349:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NameError', reason: 'uninitialized constant AppDelegate::User (NameError)
```

I can resolve the issue by explicitly stating in my Rakefile that the User class should be compiled before that AppDelegate class but that's hardly and optimal solution when you're dealing with an app with 30+ classes, many of which refer to each other.

Is there a better way to approach this issue in RubyMotion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree that using the `app.files_dependencies` approach can be burdensome once you have many classes.

In my app, I altered the `app.files` parameter instead, reordering it to put my most important things first (in my case, the `lib/` folder I added):

```
app.files = (app.files.select { |f| f =~ /app\/lib/ } + app.files).uniq
```

Comment: yea - thats what i was thinking too. hopefully this will be addressed in a future version :/

Comment: One warning: certain 3rd party libraries may stop this from working (specifically, the `bubble-wrap` gem re-orders the load path *after* you change it in your Rakefile).

Comment: The assignment should be `app.files =` instead of `+=` otherwise we're just appending to the existing array with the original load order.